# JavaScript not creating a string made up of sole white-space sub-strings?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, whitespace

So I am creating a function which is supposed to create a string made of x number of white-spaces depending on the number passed as the function argument. The problem is that when I run the code, I get the error "Invalid string length", so basically not counting white-spaces as characters.

Please see my code below:

```js
    function ajustarTexto(str, num) {
      let len = str.length;
      newstr = str;
      whtspc = (" ");
      if (len < num){
        for (let i = 0; i >= 0 ; i++){
          newstr = whtspc += whtspc;
        };
      }else if (len > num) {
          newstr.splice(num);
      };
      
      return newstr;
    };
    
    
    
    
    console.log(ajustarTexto("", 3)) // " " 
    console.log(ajustarTexto("hola", 2)) // "ho" 
    console.log(ajustarTexto("Hola", 0)) // "" 
    console.log(ajustarTexto("Hola", 5)) // "Hola "
```

I have tried to define the `whtspc` variable in different ways, but I always get the "Invalid string length" error.

Am I making any mistake?
Is there a specific way to create a white-space variable that I don't know of?

Comment: seriously ? a code with an infinite loop?

Comment: I noticed the infine loop after reading @CertainPerformace's answer. Since I didn't want to copy his code, I analyzed mine and ended up making it work with my own code. I am a couple weeks into programming, so my errors for now will be very silly most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this

```
newstr = whtspc += whtspc;
```

you're doubling the length of the `whtspc` string every iteration. That expression is equivalent to:

```
whtspc += whtspc;
newstr = whtspc;
```

So, inside the loop, `whtspc` starts at length 1, goes to 2, then 4, then 8, etc. Eventually, there's no more room and an error is thrown.

Slice the input string to the length required to remove possible excess trailing characters, then `padEnd` with spaces to fill it out to the required length, if the input string's length happened to be less than the `num`:

```js
function ajustarTexto(str, num) {
  return str.slice(0, num).padEnd(num, ' ');
}
console.log(ajustarTexto("", 3)) // " " 
console.log(ajustarTexto("hola", 2)) // "ho" 
console.log(ajustarTexto("Hola", 0)) // "" 
console.log(ajustarTexto("Hola", 5)) // "Hola "
```